Counting in Latin
As my first question on Stack Exchange I am going to ask if anyone has come upon evidence for how the Romans counted.  I.e. counting sheep, counting in rhythm, counting "One, two, three, go!"
There are possible factors such as gender of the noun counted, case depending on the context, and whether there were distinct forms different from common numerals.  E.g. Russian counts "ras, dva, tri", although ras isn't used otherwise as a numeral.

See "Im taberna quando sumus" for a good example

As far as just listing the number out, I found this sequence in Servius' Commentarius in Artem Donati:

sunt quae numerum, ut unus duo tres quattuor quinque.

It's a fourth or fifth century text, yet undoubtedly by a learned Roman. Given the tendency (e.g. in Varro, who directly states that the nominative is used in this way) to use the masculine singular when discussing adjectives, I doubt there's a problem with doing so here, too.
If the Romans are using numbers as adjectives, then you treat them like any other adjectives; but remember, most numbers don't decline.
So, in Cicero's Pro Flacco 44:

...sine quinque praetoribus, tribus quaestoribus, quattuor mensariis.
...without five praetors, three quaestors, four bankers.

Quinque and quattuor don't decline, but tribus of course is ablative as expected.
Even if the referent doesn't come immediately after the number, it can still impact the gender of the numbers, just like regular adjectives. So Varro (Lingua Latina 10.67) counting bigae—with a hypothetical singular coming first—has:

sed ut est huius ordinis una duae tres principium una, sic in hoc ordine altero unae binae trinae principium est unae.
the usual series una, duae, tres, has una as its beginning, but in this second series unae, binae, trinae, the beginning is unae. (trans. Kent 1938)

Because a feminine noun is in mind, both sets of numbers are feminine.
From the above, you should also note the exception of using the distributive form when counting words that only have plural forms (like bigae, a two-horsed chariot team), which Varro (id. 9.63) earlier has made clear:

sic unae bigae et binae et trinae bigae

See also Allen & Greenough §137 for when to use distributives at other times.
